# Code inside setup.py gets called during build only? or also during install?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

To build a package distribution, we call the setup.py file using:

python3 setup.py sdist, then, Code inside setup.py gets called and distribution is created.

Now there are 2 ways to install:

1. pip install ./dist/SomeProject-1.0.4.tar.gz
2. pip install .

**Does the setup.py file get called during install using both of the above also?** (I added print statement in the setup.py file and notice that it gets shown during build but not during install)

But the documentation says "The setup script is usually quite simple, although since it’s written in Python, there are no arbitrary limits to what you can do with it, though you should be careful about putting arbitrarily expensive operations in your setup script. Unlike, say, Autoconf-style configure scripts, **the setup script may be run multiple times in the course of building and installing your module distribution.**" https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example

**I want to run some custom code in the setup.py file only during build and not during installation. Is this possible?**

Comment: This seems easy enough to just test and see what happens...

Comment: I tried doing print but it didnt show up during install. Does that mean setup.py file does not run? The documentation says "the setup script may be run multiple times in the course of building and installing your module distribution". So I wanted advise.

Answer (score 2):

> Code inside setup.py gets called during build only? or also during install?

It depends...

If you use *setuptools* to install the project (`setup.py install` or `easy_install`) then your `setup.py` is most likely run at *install time*. If you use *pip* to install it then your `setup.py` is most likely not run at *install time*.

You should restrict the custom steps to the *build* operations that you have under control. Once you publish the distributions of your project you have little control over what exactly happens.

> I want to run some custom code in the setup.py file only during build and not during installation. Is this possible?

Yes. You need to customize the appropriate command.

Here is an example showing how to create a new custom `build_something` command that is also added as a subcommand of the default `build` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.command.build
import setuptools

class build_something(setuptools.Command):
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass
    def finalize_options(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        print(" *** build_something ***")

class build(distutils.command.build.build):
    _sub_command = (
        'build_something',
        None,
    )
    _sub_commands = distutils.command.build.build.sub_commands
    sub_commands = [_sub_command] + _sub_commands

setuptools.setup(
    name='Thing',
    version='0.0.0',
    cmdclass={
        'build_something': build_something,
        'build': build,
    },
)
```

Comment: What if I want to set version based on a string whose value I want to increment at every build

Comment: Probably feasible, but different question entirely.

Comment: Is the package version same as __version__?

Comment: It's the version string for the project you want to distribute. But again, that's a different question entirely.

Comment: @variable Does that answer you question? Any clarification needed?